# jquery trigger all input elements with blur on load

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, copy

I'm using *blur()* to copy what the user writes in a form into a summary page at the end of a registration wizard. And this is working great.

But when I preset some field values and these are correct, nothing is copied since the user probably don't gonna interacted with that particular filed. They'll just gonna click continue.

Is there a way to trigger all text fields, textareas in order get those values copied aswell?

**This is the function I'm using:**

```
/**
 *  Author: Thomas Kile
 *  Desc:   Copy text from a form element into a given tag.
 **
 *  @param string $type type of form element
 *  @param string $from Id of form element to copy text/value from.
 *  @param string $to Id of element to copy text/value into.
 */
    function copyFormData(type,from,to)
    {   
        switch (type)
        {
            case 'text':  var copied_text = $(from).val();  break; //  get input text value
            case 'select': var copied_text = $(from+' option:selected').text();  break;
        }
        $(to).text(copied_text);   //  put inside this tag
    }
```

**And this is how I'm using it:**

```
$(firstName).blur(function(){   copyFormData('text',firstName,'strong#firstName');  });
$(lastName).blur(function(){    copyFormData('text',lastName,'strong#lastName');    });
```

Where should I put a *trigger()* event?
I used *trigger()* on a select>first option once the list was fetched with getJSON in order to populate next list automatically in a chained select thing.
But that was a bit different...

Comment: not direct way but you can set all possible events like keyboard keydown and so on to handle with Your_copier function. if i didnt get point of your problem tell me please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use trick :)

```
$('input').each(function(){
  $(this).trigger('blur');
  //each input event one by one... will be blured
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').blur();
```

Or (potentially faster if everything is bound with jQuery):

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').triggerHandler('blur');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .trigger() ?

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: i think he know trigger, refer to title of question

Answer (score 0):

How about, taking your copy input to summary code and putting it into a function. keep the blur as it is (except calling this function rather than inline code) and on $(document).ready() select all of your text boxes and copy them over if they contain anything. Simpler than trying to fudge events.

Comment: just updated my first post.
I don't use inline coding, and I'm using blur as it is. I call a function I put together for this particular form when the user leaves the field...

Comment: So why not just call the copyFormData in $(document).ready to populate the defaults? Or is there a step in your form I'm missing?

Comment: Didn't understand your question.  
It's a regular form i guess. Although it's separated into three different "pages" in a scrollable similar to this: http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/wizard.html

Answer (score 0):

you could try to trigger them programmatically by firing up

```
$("selector").trigger("blur");
```

api.jquery.com/trigger is your friend :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code it will help you

```
 $('input:text').each(function(){
        $(this).trigger('blur');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happened to add the same prefix to all IDs of the input and wish to only blur these inputs all at once, you can use the wildcard selection and do it like this:

```
$("[id^=inputbox] input").trigger("blur");
```